# Tratando array com php para laravel

Tags: php, array, atributos

Estou precisando recuperar o primeiro array dessa lista de arrays.

Preciso recuperar BTC e LTC, e os atributos rate_btc, tx_fee e name.

```
array(1029) {
  ["BTC"]=>
  array(9) {
["is_fiat"]=>
int(0)
["rate_btc"]=>
string(26) "1.000000000000000000000000"
["last_update"]=>
string(10) "1375473661"
["tx_fee"]=>
string(10) "0.00040000"
["status"]=>
string(6) "online"
["name"]=>
string(7) "Bitcoin"
["confirms"]=>
string(1) "2"
["can_convert"]=>
int(1)
["capabilities"]=>
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "payments"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "wallet"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "transfers"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "convert"
} 
}
["LTC"]=>
  array(9) {
["is_fiat"]=>
int(0)
["rate_btc"]=>
string(26) "0.008875105000000000000000"
["last_update"]=>
string(10) "1538787360"
["tx_fee"]=>
string(10) "0.00200000"
["status"]=>
string(6) "online"
["name"]=>
string(8) "Litecoin"
["confirms"]=>
string(1) "3"
["can_convert"]=>
int(1)
["capabilities"]=>
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "payments"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "wallet"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "transfers"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "convert"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples amigo, só basta você selecionar os items dessa forma:

```
$btc_rate_btc = $array['BTC']['rate_btc'];
$btc_tx_fee = $array['BTC']['tx_fee'];
$btc_name = $array['BTC']['name'];

$ltc_rate_btc = $array['LTC']['rate_btc'];
$ltc_tx_fee = $array['LTC']['tx_fee'];
$ltc_name = $array['LTC']['name'];
```

Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação em português da array aqui:

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Olha la que que você vai fazer com a api da Coinpayments em!